# classify text with object javascript naive bayes classifier

Tags: javascript, text-classification, naivebayes

I will add a wordInDoc object (word: num) if the word is in the object vocab [positive], I try with equal to but fail. Why?

this is my code

```js
var nbayes = function(_class, docs) {
  var vocab = {
    positif: {
      wd: ['baik', 'pintar']
    },
    negatif: {
      wd: ['buruk', 'jelek']
    }
  }
  var wordInDoc = {}
  var sumDocs = 0;
  docs = docs.split(' ')
  var wd = 'wd'
  for (var word of docs) {
    if (word in vocab[_class][wd]) {
      var delta = 1
      wordInDoc[word] = 0
      wordInDoc[word] += delta
      sumDocs++
    }
    console.log(wordInDoc, sumDocs)
  }

};

nbayes('positif', 'baik dan rajin')
nbayes('negatif', 'nakal dan bodoh')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a solution you were looking for?

Loop through the array 'docs' then check for the index of matching in 'vocab[_class][wd]'.

Some other validation should be done for non existent classes'_class'.

```js
var nbayes = function(_class, docs) {
  var wordInDoc = {};
  var sumDocs = 0;
  var wd = 'wd';
  var word;
  var vocab = {
    positif: {
      wd: ['baik', 'pintar']
    },
    negatif: {
      wd: ['buruk', 'jelek']
    }
  }
  
  docs = docs.split(' ');
  
  for (var i = 0;i < docs.length; i++) {
    word = docs[i];
    if (vocab[_class] && vocab[_class][wd].indexOf(word) !== -1) {
      var delta = 1;
      wordInDoc[word] = 0;
      wordInDoc[word] += delta;
      sumDocs++;
    }
    console.log(wordInDoc, sumDocs)
  }

};

nbayes('positif', 'baik dan rajin')
nbayes('negatif', 'nakal dan bodoh')
```